# What do I want?

Tags: knowledge, science

I will give you some clues to figure out what I want.

### Quick facts:

1. The new SI unit of $10^3$ kilogrammes is a ton.
2. A wrist is made up of eight total bones.
3. A literature "On The Of Species" by Charles Darwin is on evolutionary biology.
4. The law $F_s=kx$ is discovered by someone.

> Three names and a word

### Learnt Vocabulary Today:

1. Cold
2. Dirty
3. Short

> Minute, Gigantic

What do I want?

*Please do not edit anything, they may be the clues for this puzzle.*

Hint:

> Oxidation, Burning, Electrolysis

Comment: Can we have another clue especially on how the two parts relate.

Comment: Oh on the hint you mean?

Comment: Could we have another

Comment: What about on the second fact that was what I can't work out.

Comment: No I meant on part about the wrist bones.

Comment: I think I have your answer...

Answer (score 3):

New answer!

You are looking for

> Sodium Hydroxide

The names and word are:

> 1)Newton, 2) Aristotle (A wrist total) 4) Hooke and the word is 3) Origin.

The facts in order in terms of the first letters spell:

> NaOH which is the chemical Sodium Hydroxide.

It fits the antonyms for the second half of the puzzle:

> 1) Hot - it can cause burns if you touch it 2) Clean - it is used in cleaning products  3) Long - it has a fairly long name.

Also for the clues:

> Sodium Hydroxide is corrosive and can burn skin, it is also known as caustic soda for this reason. It can be produced during electrolysis. It is Na combined with Oxygen due to a process called oxidation.

Comment: I got the answer!!

Comment: I'm so sorry that's not the answer. The answer is Fnygjngre

Comment: But it fits alot better I think.

Comment: I was thinking brine but I could not find the clues to fit.

Comment: I think the clues are insufficient, do you agree?

Comment: This puzzle was not really the best imho, there was little chance anyone could have deduced that with the hints let alone without it.

Answer (score 2):

Completely lost, but there's at least 1.:

> hidden in the sentence, a new ton -> Isaac Newton. "kilogramme" might be a clue as pointed by lomer

Thoughts:

> If answers to 3. and 4. are Origin (missing word) and Hooke (Hooke's law) then the answer to 2. must be the third name (three names and a word). Can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

1. The updated SI unit of $10^3$ kilogrammes is a ton.

> The *gram* used to be the SI base unit for mass, but it was updated to *kilogram* to refer to the Planck's constant, which can be used to calculate the Planck distance, which is currently the *small*est distance with meaningful experimental results. The old definition of *gram* was defined using the mass of water at 4 degrees Celsius (*cold*) occupying a cubic centimeter. The gram was first adopted by the *French* National Convention. "Kilogram" is more widely used than its British English variant "kilogramme". Using "ton" instead of "tonne" loses coherence with "kilogramme".

2. A wrist is made up of eight total bones.

> The wrist is made up of the scaphoid, trapezium, trapezoid, lunate, capitate, triquetrum, and hamate bones. The snuffbox is a depression formed by tendons near the scaphoid and trapezium bones, and is used for holding powdered tobacco. Snuff can also mean footage of homicide, which is dirty (if I do say so myself) and probably illegal. The word "total" is unnecessary.

3. A literature "On The Of Species" by Charles Darwin is on evolutionary biology

> The missing word is "Origin". The full title is "On the Origin of Species by Means of Natural Selection, or the Preservation of Favoured Races in the Struggle for Life", by Charles Darwin, an *English* naturalist. The word "literature", when used in singular, usually implies a body of work, even though it used in the sentence to refer just a single piece of work. The sentence also lacks a period at the end.

4. The law $F_s = -kx$ is found by someone.

> This law is called Hooke's law, discovered by Robert Hooke, an English physicist. It is concerned with objects in simple harmonic motion, having a force proportional to the distance from its equilibrium, like a spring getting smaller after being squashed. It's not "found", but "discovered".

The word choice of "A" and "The" may possibly contribute to the answer.

Comment: thanks for spotting! it's mass